# Save as image when right clicked on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

When `drawImage()` is used to draw something on to a canvas element, can the canvas be treated as an image?

When I right click on the drawn canvas element it dosent show the "Save image as" option.

This is the right click menu I see:

[image]

What should be done to have the "save image as" option available?

Comment: This is the default browser implementation. You need to listen for 'right click' on your canvas and display your own context menu, which will perform image saving

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu: thanks. How do I do a listener for 'right click' on the canvas to display an own context menu

Comment: Canvas normally dont change your DOM, so it s impossible to do a right clic on DOM image so you have to code it by yourself. Example : http://davidwalsh.name/html5-context-menu (i dont test it)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just overlay an image tag over the canvas with the base64 from the canvas as source

Comment: @adeneo thanks. What you say is correct but how can the base64 string be generated? Like this? `var theIMG = document.getElementById("dawenCanvas"); var cv = theIMG.getContext("2d"); var image = cv.toDataURL();  image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');` ? What if it  throws a security error like `SecurityError: The operation is insecure` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, this depends a lot on the browser and how it works and in general I wouldn't advise messing with this, but if you *have* to get this working for one reason or another there is a way: You can 'simply' convert the canvas to an `<img>` element after each draw and show the `<img>` element instead.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('exampleCanvas'); //Hidden <canvas> element
var imageFoo = document.getElementById('exampleImg'); //Visible <img> element
```

And then after each draw is finished:

```
imageFoo.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

The disadvantage here is that you will lose a lot of speed, so do not use this for animated canvases or anything like that.

Comment: Will this .`toDataURL();` throw a security error like `SecurityError: The operation is insecure` ?

Comment: @Beki: Only if the canvas has been tainted.

Comment: you've mentioned "you will lose a lot of speed" does that mean it'll consume more memory in processing or similar?

Comment: @Beki The image data itself will be stored twice in memory (or three times if you program sloppily), but that's negligible. It's more about when you try to animate the canvas that it becomes an issue (as you would see a significant drop in fps I predict)

Comment: But seriously, why do you need to do this per se in the first? If downloading the canvas is an integral part of the application a download buttion would make more sense. And if it is not then those users that want to be able to do it per se can just use a browser that supports the functionality they wish for.

Comment: One additional question: If the browser says the canvas is tainted, are there any workarounds? Because the images used to draw multiple times would be from my server itself.

Comment: @Beki Not tainting the canvas is the only solution then. Though personally I have never come across a non-hacking related situations where one would want to taint the canvas. Maybe you haven't set up your domains correctly? (e.g. with and without www)

Comment: sorry came up with something while going thru your comments. " The image data itself will be stored twice in memory " --> is there ways to clear the memory when a function is completed?

Comment: @Beki You could wipe the canvas clean, but seriously, you should not worry about those things till they hit you, because if you're asking questions like this there are a million other things that you didn't optimize either and have a bigger effect.

Answer (score 1):

The "Save as image.." is something some browsers (incl. Chrome and Firefox) includes in the context menu for convenience. It's not a standard in any way though.

You *could* emulate the right-click and provide a custom context menu with the option of save as, however, here is the caveat:

For this to work you need to have the `download` attribute in the A-tag supported as well. The problem is that for example IE, which does not provide the "Save as image.." option in the menu, neither support the `download` attribute.

The better option is probably to insert an actual image instead of or on top of the canvas when completed (depending on how the alpha channel is used). This may not always be feasible if the content is dynamic and constantly updating, and there is CORS restrictions at play as well for images loaded from external sources.

**In conclusion:** There is little one can do to make a solid workaround for this. It is and will be a browser feature pretty much (and being selective about which browser to support is already the case with the feature itself, so no gain here...).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want to download the picuture on the canvas:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="gb">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="test"></canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById('test');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.font = "30px Arial";
            ctx.fillText("Noel Rocks",10, 50);

            canvas.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            var image_png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

            var download = document.createElement('a');
            download.href = image_png;
            download.download = "canvas.png";

            var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            evObj.initEvent( "click", true, false );
            download.dispatchEvent(evObj)

            }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically it overwrites the context menu, sets up a link with the canvas as a png and then sends the click event to the link. I have used the [Download](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) attribute which isn't available in any version of IE or Safari so might not really be fit for general use.